# Is the variation of a metric with respect to a metric with a different signature, zero?

Tags: differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations

I have a problem that involves calculating the variation of a metric $ \bar{g}_{\alpha\beta} $ with +3 signature with respect to a metric $ g_{\alpha\beta} $ with a signature of +1. Both metrics have the same spatial dimension of 3. The metrics are related by $ g_{\alpha\beta}=\bar{g}_{\alpha\beta}-2u_{\alpha}u_{\beta} $ where u is a unit vector in $ \bar{g}$, i.e. ($ u_{\alpha}u^{\alpha}=1 $),  and $ u_{\alpha}u^{\alpha}=-1 $ in g. Since the signature of a metric is constant everywhere, it seems trivial that $\dfrac{\delta \bar{g}_{\alpha\beta}}{\delta g_{\alpha\beta}}   =0$. Am I missing something?

Comment: The dependence of $\bar g$ on $g$ could completely ignore the signature - this question cannot be answered one way or the other without knowing the relationship. I suggest you add this to your question. If the relationship is simply $\bar g = g + 2 u \otimes u$ as your comment suggests, then $\delta \bar g/\delta g$ will be the identity, not zero.

Comment: Anthony, these two metrics have different signatures everywhere. How can $\dfrac{\delta \bar{g}_{\alpha\beta}}{\delta g_{\alpha\beta}}  =1$ ?

Comment: Because if $\bar g(g) = g + 2 u \otimes u$ then $$\delta \bar g/\delta g [h] = \frac{d}{ds}|_{s=0} \bar g(g + s h) = \frac{d}{ds}|_{s=0}\left( g + sh + 2 u \otimes u \right) = h.$$ If this is not what you mean, then you need to better describe how $\bar g$ is a function of $g$. I don't see how the fact that the signatures are different should imply the derivative is zero.

Comment: The canonical form of $ \bar{g} $ is (1,1,1) and that of g is (-1,1,1) because of the stated properties of the unit vector in each metric. Your variation did not involve the unit vectors which have differing signs of their scalar product in each metric.

Comment: Are you saying $u$ also depends on $g$?

Comment: I still don't have any idea what you're trying to get at with the signature argument - consider the simple example $\bar g = - g$, which sends signature $+n$ to signature $-n$ but clearly has non-zero derivative.

Comment: In g, $ u_{\alpha}u^{\alpha}=-1 $ everywhere. I like your approach to actually doing the variation but the constraint $ u_{\alpha}u^{\alpha}+1=0 $ needs to be in the calculation. $ u_{\alpha}u^{\alpha}=g_{\alpha\beta}u^\alpha u^\beta $ involves g.

Comment: Since $g(u,u)=-1$ carves out a subset of the tangent bundle with two dimensions over each point, if you vary $g$ then there are many different ways to vary $u$ while maintaining this constraint. Thus my expectation is the best you can do from this information is some formula for $\delta \bar g / \delta g$ in terms of $\delta u / \delta g$, which will be constrained (but not uniquely).

Answer (score 0):

If you treat $\bar g = g + 2u\otimes u$ as a function of $g$ and $u$ separately, the "partial variational derivatives" are $$\frac{\delta \bar g_{\alpha\beta} }{ \delta g }[h]= h_{\alpha\beta}$$ and $$\frac{\delta \bar g_{\alpha \beta} }{ \delta u }[v] = 2 u_{(\alpha}  v_{\beta)},$$ so once you have chosen a functional relationship $g \mapsto u(g)$ the total derivative is $$\frac{\delta}{\delta g} \left(\bar g (g,u(g))\right)[h] = h + 2 u \odot \frac{\delta u}{\delta g}[h]$$ where $\odot$ denotes the symmetric tensor product.

Thus we have reduced your question to asking how $u$ varies when you vary $g$. The constraint $g(u,u)=-1$ is not enough to determine this, since this defines a hyperboloid on which we can freely slide $u$ around. It does somewhat constrain the variation, however: differentiating the constraint with respect to $g$ we find $$h(u,u) + 2g \left(u,\frac{\delta u}{\delta g}[h]\right) = 0.$$

As an example, we could choose $\delta u/\delta g[h]=0$ in directions $h$ satisfying $h(u,u) = 0$, in which case the total derivative in these directions would be $\delta \bar g/\delta g[h] = h \ne 0.$ If you have a more explicit description of $u(g)$ then perhaps I can say more, but I don't think there's any choice that makes the derivative vanish.

**Edit:** Here's an explicit example in which the derivative is nonzero. Suppose we are working on $\mathbb R^3$, and the point at which we are differentiating is where $g_0$ is the Minkowski metric, $\bar g_0$ is the Euclidean metric and $u_0 = \partial_t$ is the standard time translation field. (This is really just for convenience - all of this could be adapted locally to any example.) For metrics $g$ sufficiently close to $g_0$ in the sup norm, the field $$ u(g) =\frac{\partial_t}{\sqrt{-g(\partial_t,\partial_t)}}$$ is smooth (in both spacetime and with respect to $g$) and satisfies your requirements. Now, if we choose the variation $h = dx \otimes dx$, note that $u(g_0 + \epsilon h) = u(g_0)$ since $u$ depends only on the component $g_{tt}$. Thus we have $$\frac{\delta \bar g_{xx}}{\delta g}\Big|_{g_0} = \frac{\delta \bar g}{\delta g}\Big|_{g_0}[h] = \frac{d}{d \epsilon}\Big|_{\epsilon = 0}(g_0+\epsilon h) = h \ne 0.$$

Comment: To understand my results, you need to complete the calculation of $ g^{\alpha\beta}\delta g_{\alpha\beta} $ which is equivalent to $ g^{\alpha\beta} \delta\bar{g}_{\alpha\beta}-2u^{\alpha}u^{\beta}\delta g_{\alpha\beta} $ using $ g^{\alpha\beta}\delta (u_{\alpha}u_{\beta})=u^{\alpha}u^{\beta}\delta g_{\alpha\beta} $. What is for certain is that $ u^{\alpha}u^{\beta}\neq0 $ and thus the contradiction to  $\dfrac{\delta \bar{g}_{\alpha\beta}}{\delta g_{\alpha\beta}}   \neq0$.

Comment: You have treated u as a separate variation instead of working with the product $u^{\alpha}u^{\beta}$ which has led to an incorrect result.

Comment: @Kolten: in my example $u$ does not vary in the $h$ direction and thus $u^\alpha u^\beta$ doesn't either. To put it intuitively, $g$ and $\bar g$ differ only in the timelike direction; so if we change $g$ in a spacelike direction we must also change $\bar g$.

Answer (score 0):

The question is more complex than I thought. However, it seems that $\dfrac{\delta \bar{g}_{\alpha\beta}}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}}   =0$ is the only condition that satisfies the two metrics defined by $g_{\alpha\beta}=\bar{g}_{\alpha\beta}-2u_{\alpha}u_{\beta} $ where u is a unit vector in $ \bar{g} $, i.e. $u_{\alpha}u^{\alpha}=1  $, and $ u_{\alpha}u^{\alpha}=-1 $ in g.  We can check that $ g^{\alpha\beta}=\bar{g}^{\alpha\beta}-2u^{\alpha}u^{\beta} $ is the inverse of $ g_{\alpha\beta} $ by calculating $ g_{\alpha\beta}g^{\alpha\mu}=\delta_{\beta}^{\mu} $. Let's assume $\dfrac{\delta \bar{g}_{\alpha\beta}}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}} \neq 0$. With $ \delta $ standing for $\dfrac{\delta} {\delta g_{\mu\nu}} $, we have $ g^{\alpha\beta}\delta(u_{\alpha}u_{\beta})=-u_{\alpha}u_{\beta} \delta g^{\alpha\beta}$ from $ u_{\alpha}u^{\alpha}=-1 $ and $ \delta g_{\alpha\beta}=\delta \bar{g}_{\alpha\beta}-2\delta (u_{\alpha}u_{\beta}) $. Calculating $ g^{\alpha\beta}\delta g_{\alpha\beta} $ gives $\bar{g}^{\alpha\beta}\delta g_{\alpha\beta}=g^{\alpha\beta}\delta \bar{g}_{\alpha\beta} $. Setting $\alpha=\mu$ and $\beta=\nu$ gives $ \bar{g}^{\alpha\beta}{1}_{\alpha\beta}=(\bar{g}^{\alpha\beta}-2u^{\alpha}u^{\beta})(\dfrac{\delta\bar{g}}{\delta g}) _{\alpha\beta}$. This requires $ (\dfrac{\delta\bar{g}}{\delta g}) _{\alpha\beta}={1}_{\alpha\beta} $ and $u^{\alpha}u^{\beta}{1}_{\alpha\beta}=0 $ which is impossible. We assumed and used $\dfrac{\delta \bar{g}_{\alpha\beta}}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}} \neq 0$ so the assumption must be wrong. The only solution is then $\dfrac{\delta \bar{g}_{\alpha\beta}}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}}   =0$ and $\dfrac{\delta (u_{\alpha}u_{\beta})}{\delta g_{\alpha\beta}}   =-1/2{1}_{\alpha\beta}$.

Comment: I don't follow your calculation, and your conclusion is certainly wrong - see my edit.

Comment: Where did you *use* the assumption that $\delta \bar g / \delta g \ne 0$? Looks to me like your contradiction really shows that your reasoning is faulty. Written out in full, the equation you arrive at (correctly as far as I can tell) is $$\bar g^{\mu \nu} = (\bar g_{\alpha \beta} - 2 u_\alpha u_\beta)\dfrac{\delta \bar g_{\alpha \beta}}{\delta g_{\mu \nu}}.$$ Why does this imply $\delta \bar g / \delta g = 1$ and $u \otimes u = 0$?

Comment: Firstly, your indices in the bracketed term should be upper, not lower. Secondly, you construct the  variation of $\bar{g}_{\alpha\beta}$ in the first step of the calculation, from the relationship between the metrics. That is assumed to not vanish. You end up with a comparison of $\bar{g}^{\mu\nu}$ on the LHS to $\bar{g}^{\alpha\beta}$ in the RHS. Take $\alpha=\mu$ and $\beta=\nu$. This requires the $\dfrac{\delta \bar{g}_{\alpha\beta}}{\delta g_{\alpha\beta}}=1$ and $u^{\alpha}u^{\beta}=0$.

Comment: This requires the stated conditions so in general Firstly, your indices in the bracketed term should be upper, not lower. Secondly, you construct the  variation of $\bar{g}_{\alpha\beta}$ in the first step of the calculation, from the relationship between the metrics. That is assumed to not vanish. You end up with a comparison of $\bar{g}^{\mu\nu}$ on the LHS to $\bar{g}^{\alpha\beta}$ in the RHS. Take $\alpha=\mu$ and $\beta=\nu$. This requires the $\dfrac{\delta \bar{g}_{\alpha\beta}}{\delta g_{\alpha\beta}}=1$ and $u^{\alpha}u^{\beta}=0$.

Comment: Please ignore the previous comment as it timed out on me while editing.

Comment: But $u^{\alpha}u^{\beta}$ cannot vanish and we have the stated contradiction

Comment: You can't take $\alpha = \mu, \beta = \nu$ when $\alpha,\beta$ are already being summed over. What you're doing is essentially the same as the following: suppose we know $v^i = T^i_j (v^j + w^j).$ Then setting $i=j$, we must have $w=0$ and $T^i_i = 1$. Do you see the problem? You're playing fast and loose with notation. This equation has many solutions. You made a similar error when you just checked $g^{\alpha\beta}g_{\alpha\beta} = 3$ and concluded you had the correct inverse - you happened to be right, but to prove it you need to show $g^{\alpha\beta}g_{\beta \gamma} = \delta^\alpha_\gamma.$

Comment: Anthony, taking $\alpha=\mu$ and $\beta=\nu$ is a part of the sum. If there is a contradiction as the result of part of a sum, the complete sum implies the contradiction. You are certainly correct on the Kronecker delta for the inverse, which I obviously checked after finding a candidate for the inverse the  easiest way (to me) by calculating n first; that is just the approach I take.

Comment: But you are picking out a single term in the sum on the RHS and claiming it is equal to the entirety of the LHS.

Comment: Yes, if we look at the cases when $\alpha=\mu$ and $\beta=\nu$ there is a contradiction in the sum. It takes only one case to show a contradiction; not the entire cases in the sum.

Comment: I suggest you think more carefully about what Anthony wrote. An even simpler example of why you cannot equate one term of a sum on the RHS to the entire LHS would be, in dimension $d\geq 2$, $v_i = \delta^j_i v_j$, which is an identity for an arbitrary 1-form $v$. But try taking $j\neq i$ on the RHS. You would then mistakenly conclude $v_i=0$ for an arbitrary 1-form.

Comment: In the sum, there is a contradiction. It takes one contradiction to prove the point, not every possible result in a sum.

Comment: Anthony, I noticed that the expression you arrived at above, $ \bar{g}^{\mu\nu}=(\bar{g}_{\alpha\beta}-2u_{\alpha}u_{\beta})\dfrac{\delta\bar{g}_{\alpha\beta}}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}} $ should be $ \bar{g}^{\alpha\beta}\dfrac{\delta g_{\alpha\beta}}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}}=(\bar{g}^{\alpha\beta}-2u^{\alpha}u^{\beta})\dfrac{\delta\bar{g}_{\alpha\beta}}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}}  $. Hence, the confusion.

Comment: Assume the Hodge conjecture is false. Then $6 = 1 + 2 + 3 = \sum_{k=1}^3 k.$  Take $k=3$ and we find $6=3,$ a contradiction! 1 million dollars please.

Comment: No-one appreciates condescending BS especially when that person has made mistakes and are trying to cover them up with such statements. Look at your expression and look at the correct one. No wonder you come up with examples that have nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: You're being extremely arrogant for someone who came here looking for help. My examples are directly disproving the claim you are making - there's clearly some gap in understanding here that your stubbornness is not helping us resolve. Anyway, forgive me my facetious jab. I mixed up some index placement, but this is not the main source of confusion here. If you don't agree $\dfrac{\delta g_{\alpha \beta}}{\delta g_{\mu \nu}} = \delta_\alpha^\mu \delta_\beta^\nu$ then I'm not sure what you mean when you write a variational derivative with indices in the denominator.

Comment: Alright. Let's start over. First of all, please check your work so that we agree on $\bar{g}^{\alpha\beta}\dfrac{\delta g_{\alpha\beta}}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}}=(\bar{g}^{\alpha\beta}-2u^{\alpha}u^{\beta})\dfrac{\delta\bar{g}_{\alpha\beta}}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}}  $. The sum in that expression I was talking about, is totally different from that in yours. Hence the confusion.

Comment: This requires $ (\dfrac{\delta\bar{g}}{\delta g}) _{\alpha\beta}=I_{\alpha\beta} $ and $u^{\alpha}u^{\beta}I_{\alpha\beta}=0 $ which is impossible. We assumed and used $\dfrac{\delta \bar{g}_{\alpha\beta}}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}} \neq 0$ so the assumption must be wrong.

Comment: We can't use Kronecker product on one side of the equation only, and I am not sure it applies to the variation with different metrics, so let's use the identity matrix I to replace it with the understanding there is no sum on $ \alpha $ and $ \beta $. Choosing $\alpha=\mu$ and $\beta=\nu$, we get $ \bar{g}^{\alpha\beta}I_{\alpha\beta}=(\bar{g}^{\alpha\beta}-2u^{\alpha}u^{\beta})(\dfrac{\delta\bar{g}}{\delta g}) _{\alpha\beta}$.

Comment: This last comment makes no sense to me, how are taking an equality that is only known to be true when summed and then claiming it holds unsummed? I also don't understand why you're replacing $\delta g_{\alpha \beta}/\delta g_{\mu \nu}$ with $I_{\alpha \beta}$ - what do you really mean by the former? I interpret it as the rate of change of $g_{\alpha \beta}$ when we increase the component $g_{\mu \nu}$ (and thus $g_{\nu \mu}$ too, to retain symmetry) at unit speed, which is of course $\delta_{(\alpha}^\mu \delta_{\beta)}^\nu.$

Comment: Once you work out a consistent way to use notation, you will find that my example satisfies this equation. For example, a physicist might write it like this: If $g$ is Minkowski and $u = \partial_t$ (so that $\bar g$ is Euclidean), the non-zero variations $\delta \bar g_{\alpha \beta} = \delta g_{\alpha \beta} = \delta_\alpha^x \delta_\beta^x$ satisfy $$\bar{g}^{\alpha\beta}\delta g_{\alpha\beta}=(\bar{g}^{\alpha\beta} -2u^{\alpha}u^{\beta})\delta \bar{g}_{\alpha\beta}.$$

Comment: Sorry for the confusion as I was trying to avoid using the delta product not knowing if it applied to different metrics. The sum is of course there and I was looking at each piece of the sum with lousy notation ($I_{\alpha\beta}$ was meant to apply to all components and not just the diagonal; i.e. a full identity).

Comment: We can't use Kronecker product because it does not preserve the sum.  The identity element $\mathds{1}$ should be used when choosing $\alpha=\mu$ and $\beta=\nu$. We get $ \bar{g}^{\alpha\beta}\mathds{1}_{\alpha\beta}=(\bar{g}^{\alpha\beta}-2u^{\alpha}u^{\beta})(\dfrac{\delta\bar{g}}{\delta g}) _{\alpha\beta}$. This requires $ (\dfrac{\delta\bar{g}}{\delta g}) _{\alpha\beta}=\mathds{1}_{\alpha\beta} $ and $u^{\alpha}u^{\beta}\mathds{1}_{\alpha\beta}=0 $ which is impossible. We assumed and used $\dfrac{\delta \bar{g}_{\alpha\beta}}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}} \neq 0$ so the assumption must be wrong.